# Why am I getting random 500 errors on my MVC and ASP websites on iis7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc, asp

It seems to happen on almost every site and does not matter if it is an ASP or .NET website.  if you refresh right after you get that error it goes away and won't come back by just hitting refresh a bunch of times.  I have two servers working with load balancing for IIS. *EDIT* Also these are valid paths for folder names.  The pages connect to a Microsoft SQL databse on aother server.  Application pools are setup to use a different domain user for all of the A websites as well as for every other letter of the alphabet as instructed by microsoft.  Each website has its own application pool. *EDIT*  [image: Basic 500 Error]

Comment: Is it possible there is a limit to the amount of network connections a single username can create or have?  The way my Application pools are setup it that all the application pools that start with A use the username A. and ll the B's use B's. etc.  I am wondering if there are too many network connections and it is causing these 500 errors.

Answer (score 3):

Try "not" load balancing the servers to see if one of the servers is responsible.

Comment: we had these issues before the load balancing was implemented, have not had the secondary server run by itself yet.  I will try that and let you guys know how it goes.

Comment: It does not seem to matter which server is on with the load balancing.  I see 500 errors in both servers logs for different sites.

Answer (score 2):

The error also states "Error Code 0x80070035", which is outlined in detail on Microsofts site: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942031.

The error basically means "Access Denied", the folder cannot be accessed by IIS, I would start by checking the permissions of that folder. You will want to ensure that IIS has at least read access to that folder and the files within. If the website utilizes scripts, you will also probably want to allow execute access on the scripts.

Comment: I understand this and it does have permission.  Again 99% of the time this does not happen.  If you go to the page 500 times it will happen maybe once or twice.  It is not a permission issue that I can tell because if it was it would be constant.

Comment: Oh my. Welcome to the club, I have an old IIS 6 that I want to kick to the curb so bad, but owners don't want give it up (or let it down). It also spits out a random ODBC error every once in a while, the page will continue to error for about 2 minutes then revert to working fine.

Comment: Ok but that's an iis6 server that is old.  These are new servers and iis7.  Is there anything you can tell me specifically about iis7 having network connectivity issues?

Answer (score 1):

My original answer got eaten by an error, so here goes the short version:

The error says it's probably permissions, but this looks like an assumption based on what it was trying to do at the time. Connectivity looks like a good possible additional cause.

The error is from the Static File Handler, which implies any active content wasn't executing; the request wasn't yet authenticated. So app code isn't implicated here.

The content appears to be on a UNC share.

- Are "all websites" on that same server?
- Does the problem really affect "all websites" or just "all websites on that file server"? (Is that the same thing?)
- Can you move one or more of the site(s) locally to see if that fixes it?

A network capture seems like it *might* help if it covers a problem instance.

App Event Logs would probably also help, if there are any relevant entries.

In short: could be that the client (IIS) and the file server aren't always on good terms; looking at network-related problems seems like the right approach, assuming the SMB-related due diligence (MaxCmds etc) is already sorted out.

Comment: I get calls from different customers almost everyday about different websites.  I can't confirm yet that it happens to each website but it is not the same ones over and over.  I have also been getting 500.19 errors which states the web.config is invalid, and again once refreshed will work just fine.  I am unsure what you mean about the smb-related due dilligence and maxcmds.  Could you please elaborate on this?  I will move a known site that has issues to the local machine and disable load balancing to try to confirm network issues.